# localhost server in compiled Python program

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, user-interface, localhost

**Background:**

I am still new to Python so apologies if this is a naive question. I was originally looking to develop a tool for Windows with a GUI, however, reading around I get the impression that it may be simpler to have my compiled python code somehow 'wrapped' in [simpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) so users can interact via localhost (much like Jupyter notebook/labs).

**Question:**

Is there a standard/recommended way to have a compiled python program interface with the user via a localhost port in their web browser? I assume this is a fairly common approach and that a package may already even exist but I've not been able to find anything that gives guidance on how to tackle it.

---

Alternatively, is is feasible to somehow compile a Django development project to run on localhost?

Ideally, I want an executable file that users can run and their browser opens up at the localhost port required.

Comment: Can docker help you in your case ?

Comment: Depending on your use-case, starting/using a python server from nw.js might be part of a solution..? (https://nwjs.io/)

Comment: `webbrowser.open(url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to quickly make a GUI based Python tool, you should consider using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), a very straightforward framework for WebApps. It is very quick to learn and implement, and you shall very easily be able to integrate highly advanced functionalities too into your tool with ease.

When it comes to distribution of code, you can convert the entire Django App into a windows exe file for ease of distribution and use. There are many python packages that allow you to port python to windows executable files. I would recommend using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). You may find this link useful: [Recipe Executable From Django](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Executable-From-Django).

Alternatively, as someone suggested, you may use Docker, but that would be heavier in terms of space utilized, and will require the user to install the same.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is great - exactly what I was hoping to hear! Thank you for the "Django recipe" link too!